How can I alter a Minecraft Mob's appearance?
I'm curious if Vanilla Minecraft allows you to use the /summon command and use JSON like data to alter mobs' appearance, like change its dimensions, skin, strength, speed, knockback, API (like a Skeleton floating and firing up like a blaze, a villager shooting bow and arrows, a ghast that stays on the ground, or a Baby Zombie blowing up like a creeper, the horror), and whatever else to curse these mobs?
Disclaimer, I previously labeled this as Java and Bedrock, so some of the answers are meant for Bedrock.

I think this is a fair technical question, and it's complete; can stand on its own

I think it should focus on one platform, and at least ask how to alter the appearance of a single mob; not also for other players (because I think that requires quite a different command). Can you also add what you've tried so far?

Well, I have tried things like the villager buy.sell features. I'm just not sure what else there is. I'm not the greatest on commands, cause I'm new to them, so this is why I'm asking.

Your edit doesn't really make the question much clearer (and you disqualify parts of the existing answers, but that's a catch-22 at this point). What do you want to change, what is the outcome you envision? And please [edit] in what you've tried, preferably with the exact commands. (I know this is annoying, but it's how we try to keep a high standard of quality content here.)

You can modify all mobs in Minecraft, giving them:

Custom Textures
Custom Models
Custom Animations

If it's in the resource pack specification, you can do it.
However, you can't create new variants (like with CustomModelData for blocks and items)*.
In Bedrock however, there is the ability to create a new custom entity based off an existing one, or a dummy one that you will need write command blocks or behaviours to make do something..
*you can still modify existing variants, like with villagers, cats and wolves but you can't make more Armadillos, Skeletons or Zombies.
See also: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Resource_pack#Animation

However, if you add modding; with Optfine, you can make variants, conditionals (ie. based on how damaged a mob/item is, or any NBT flags it might have) and animated textures, amongst other things.
See also: https://optifine.readthedocs.io/cem.html

For MCBE just Install Bridge or use the Web Version and using Blockbench, you can create models and textures also for MCJE, I don't have Java so I can't recommend anything like Bridge but is for Java.

Java also uses Blockbench; it supports both model formats :)

yes i know: "and using Blockbench, you can create models and textures for MCJE"
